# jQuery :cant use split function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery autocomplete pluggin .

I have the following code

```
$().ready(function() {

    function findValueCallback(event, data, formatted) {
        $("<li>").html( !data ? "No match!" : "Selected: " + formatted)
            .appendTo("#result");
    }

});
```

I am trying to split the value coming in data.When i alert it,It is showing properly.But i cant use a split method to extract some data from it .(the data is "ASP.ASPItems.23" , I want to take that 23 from it

When i use split,I am getting an error like "split is undefined"

My split code

```
var subjectId=data.split(".")[2]
```

CAn any one advice how to go ahead

Comment: Most likely data is not a string. What is typeof(data) ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well seeing as split is a method defined on a string, have you considered trying `data.toString().split(".")` or `String(data).split(".")` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = $("input[name='campstarttime\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

var result = values.toString().split(",") ;

alert(result[1]);
```